# Toggle icon color upon button click using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm a newbie to React. I'm trying to update the like or bookmark count to `0` and `1` upon button click. When I click on the bookmark icon, both the icons gets toggled. The behavior seems inconsistent.

**ToggleIcon Component**

```
const ToggleIcon = ({ icon, color, styledIcon, handleClick }: any) => {
  return (
    <IonIcon icon={color ? styledIcon : icon} onClick={handleClick}></IonIcon>
  );
};
```

**Root Component**

```
  {config.map((props, index) => (
    <ToggleIcon
      style={{ padding: "10px" }}
      handleClick={() => {
        setColor(!color);

        if (props.type === "bookmark") {
           !color && props.type === "bookmark"
           ? setBookmarkCount(bookmarkCount + 1)
           : setBookmarkCount(bookmarkCount - 1);
        }

        if (props.type === "like") {
            !color && props.type === "like"
            ? setLikeCount(likeCount + 1)
            : setLikeCount(likeCount - 1);
        }
      }}
      color={color}
      {...props}
     />
  ))}
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-butterfly-brezp?file=/src/pages/Tab1/Tab1.tsx). Could anyone please help?

Comment: I don't overly see the point of the config array if you are limiting yourself to only two static values (like / bookmark) seems like you are making things harder on yourself. If you want to keep using your config and remain able to specify any number of icons you probably want something more along the lines of: [https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-violet-ih1mv](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-violet-ih1mv)

Comment: Just to make that slightly clearer, the issue you were experiencing is you have no way to determine which icon you intended to color from just a single boolean (the `color={color}`), using your original state you would need to have a function that would check if `color` was true and the corresponding count was greater than 0 (at that point you don't really need the color flag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is using a single `color` state to toggle the icon color. Whenever you click on any icon it triggers a change in the color state which rerenders the entire component with that `color` state.

I tried using multiple states for `LikeColor` and `BookColor` and it worked like a charm.[Solution Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-nash-de8k9?file=/src/pages/Tab1/Tab1.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bas-m11m7?file=/src/pages/Tab1/Tab1.tsx)

You need to separate the color into two different states. The way you have it written, one boolean value is driving the color for both the bookmark and icon color on line 27. Just because you have a loop on line 51 does not change the fact that there is only one setColor function, which you end up using twice for both `<ToggleIcon/>`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by now you are better in react. Just pointing out for someone else who might need this solution. Your conditional statement inside handleClick is a bit messed up

```js
if (props.type === "bookmark") {
           !color && props.type === "bookmark"
           ? setBookmarkCount(bookmarkCount + 1)
           : setBookmarkCount(bookmarkCount - 1);
        }

        if (props.type === "like") {
            !color && props.type === "like"
            ? setLikeCount(likeCount + 1)
            : setLikeCount(likeCount - 1);
        }
      }}
      color={color}
      {...props}
```

Should include an else statement instead of 2 if(s) statements  see docs below
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html